Can't connect to the network
My operating system is Ubuntu 22.04 desktop. I upgraded my VPN and manually installed some packages and deleted some packages. Then I found the system cannot connect to the network in any way.
I installed the same system on the disk in another place. Is there any way to fix this problem?
No WiFi:

IP link:

and this is /var/log/apt/history.log
enter image description here
and this is /var/log/dpkg.log
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here

You are more likely to get useful help if your question includes more detail. Like what packages you deleted and installed.

What WiFi-card do you have? What is the output of ip link? [Edit] your question with it.

ip link showed here

i forgot what i delete and installed

You can try checking /var/log/apt/history.log and /var/log/dpkg.log (which might be archived in older index files in the same directory). Also, try backing up your current iptables rules and then resetting them to default. Additionally, checking whether USB tethering to share WiFi is working can help determine if the issue is related to the WiFi adapter or firewall/iptables rules.
